# The Applications in Settings page is still showing SE application for Android

Tags: feature-request, android-app, stack-exchange

The Stack Exchange Android app has been removed from [Google Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play), but the *Applications* option in the *Settings* page is still showing the SE application for Android.

[image]

Yes, we can remove them manually by clicking the remove option, but can this option showing **SE for Android** be disabled for all who have used the app earlier as the app is no longer available?

Comment: What link needs to be disabled?

Comment: @rene I meant the option which shows **SE for Android**

Comment: Can’t you still use the app if you have it downloaded?

Comment: @Laurel I've uninstalled the app long before it's been removed from the play store.

Comment: I think it is weird if what you authorized gets fiddled with. I even believe the text is static once you authorized, aka its stored with your profile. Changing /  disabling would be a one-off with little gain. Let's not do this.

Comment: How would the website know that?

Comment: FWIW, I'm still using the Android app, and since it's Android, there are safe alternative market sites where you can download the APK and install it again.

Comment: Likewise and it's an essential tool as a mod for me